# How to upload multiple files with extension checking in yii2 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, yii2

I am using AngularJS to upload an Array of `formData` to PHP

```
// sample code in ng-component.js
const fd = new FormData();
for (let i=0; i < $scope.brochureList.length; i++) {
  console.log($scope.brochureList[i].image_url);
  fd.append('brochure_file[]', $scope.brochureList[i].image_url[0]
}
```

console.log($scope.brochureList[i].image_url 
[image: console.log($scope.brochureList[i].image_url]

```
// Controller file
$form = new UpdateForm()
$form->brochure = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('brochure_file');

throw new \Exception(var_export($form->brochure,2), 1);


// UpdateForm.php
class UpdateForm extends Model
{
  public $brochure;
  
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
      [['brochure'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg, pdf', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 5, 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false, 'maxFiles' => 0],
    ]
  }
}
```

throw new \Exception(var_export($form->brochure,2), 1);
[image: $form->brochure]

In this case the video that was uploaded should be blocked due to `extensions` and `maxSize` rule but it was not, and my `throw new \Exception` line was run instead. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: can you run $form->validate() and see $form->getErrors()